# Why did all of the magic disappear immediately when X(A/N)th left Xanth?

Tags: magical-theory, xanth

X(A/N)<sup>th</sup> is described as letting off magic like body heat:

> "I did indeed. The Demon X(A/N)<sup>th</sup> has been confined here over a thousand years. From his body has leaked a trace amount of magic, infusing the surrounding material. Hardly enough for him to notice—just a natural emanation of his presence, much as our own bodies give off heat."
>   Bink found this as fascinating as the Demon's vortex-Thoughts. "A thousand years? Leakage of magic?"
>   "In that time even a small leak can amount to a fair amount—at least it might seem that way to vermin," the Magician assured him. "All the magic of the Land of Xanth derives from this effect—and all of it together would not make up a single letter of the Demon's formula."
>   <sub>*The Magic of Zanth*, book 2: *The Source of Magic*, chapter 12</sub>

In that case, when he disappeared, why did all of the magic stop immediately? Why didn't the magic that had already leaked into Xanth stay there and dissipate more slowly, like a rock cooling off after somebody stops leaning on it? Shouldn't the magic that had already leaked into Xanth (a thousand years worth!) have stayed there, and then dissipated after X(A/N)<sup>th</sup> was no longer there?

**Why did all of the magic cease immediately?**

Answer (score 6):

**It didn't**.

> "He's leaked a lot of magic here," Bink said. "It is quiescent without him, but so long as magical creatures like dragons and centaurs remain, we know it hasn't departed entirely.
>
> *(Chapter 14, "Paradox Wish")*

It appears that talents (as well as 'spell effects' such as petrification) did vanish immediately:

> His talent must have saved him, just before it faded. He could not depend on it any more, however; it was evident that spells had been the first magic to go.
>
> *(Chapter 13, Magic Loss)*

but magical creatures were only slowly affected:

> "In time you will change into your dominant mundane component, or your offspring will. I think that would be a large snake. I'm sorry."
>
> The dragon stared at him in horror. Then it whipped about and half-galloped, half-slithered off.

and

> They [*goblins*] seemed to have been bred from men and rats. Now that the magic was gone, the man-aspect was diminishing and the rat-aspect was becoming more pronounced.
>
> *(both from Chapter 13, Magic Loss)*

But even this isn't entirely explained (maybe not entirely consistent) as the tangle trees do become immediately inert...

Comment: taking time to loose the magic makes sense, and as for tangle trees (and some other phenomena) immediately fading, well, sunlight-to-shade feels cooler immediately, even though the actual temperature takes time to drop (ie, night vs daytime temperatures).  Could be the *difference* was just noticeable, and some magics had more difficulty sustaining themselves on those lesser amounts available.

Comment: Yeah, probably something like that. The tangle trees bit just seems weird because centaurs (who are pretty anatomically unworkable) seem totally OK and dragons have just lost their overt powers like fire, but retain intelligence etc... yet the tangle tree is dead or as inert as a normal plant.

Comment: @cometaryorbit A Centaur may have needed magic to maintain their form over generations, but they use non-magic, mundane musculature to move around. A tangle tree on the other hand may be an inert tree using magic for fast movement. In that case, the rapidly vanishing magic would render those trees motionless.